# Timeout and unset 1 query in multi curl

Tags: php, curl

I have php script that send request to the other server.

If the question similar to each other, I using multi curl

```
try {                                                                
    $result['response'][] = @new SimpleXMLElement($task);               
    $result['request'][] = @new SimpleXMLElement($request);             

} catch (Exception $e) {                                             
    // Showing err
    if ($throwException) {                                              
        throw new Exception('Internal Server Error', 500);            
    }                                                                   
}
```

If any problem with answer I showing an error.

---

I want to know:

**1)** How to understand that it was timeout error or something else?

```
$cmh = curl_multi_init(); // create only one descriptor
```

If I send 5 request, 4 will be ok, and by 1 will be timeout()

**2)** How to unset only this one request in multi curl?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this CURL class:

http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading

```
$curl = new CURL();
$curl->retry = 2;
$opts = array( CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true  );
$curl->addSession( 'http://yahoo.com/', $opts );
$curl->addSession( 'http://yahoo.co.uk/', $opts );
$curl->addSession( 'http://yahoo.ru/', $opts );
$result = $curl->exec();
$curl->clear();
foreach( $result as $r )
{
    if( $r['info']['http_code'] !== 200 )
        echo $r['url'] . " has failed\n";
}
```

I may have some of the variables in the foreach wrong there. Just print_r( $r['info'] ); and you will get all the details for each request. This also has a retry for failed requests ($curl->retry = 2;).

Comment: I think, that I need to set timeout less then 30sec in to descriptor?

Comment: Change to this: $opts = array( CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30 );

Comment: Thank's but I already find, how to fix it.
We create handler for each query, then add them to multi handler, after responce we can filter them by code answer. And remove query with error. But thanks anyway!